# Makefile - Dependency file in a folder "No such file or directory"

Tags: build, makefile, dependencies

I've got a Makefile that works good so far. Although, as it started growing, recompiling all the sources every time began to take too long. Here's a snippet from the working version:

```
CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -I./include -pg -O2
VPATH=./src:./include

all: dotgazer.cpp dotgazer/Dot.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o dotgazer.out `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

There are a lot more dependencies, but these two are enough to show what the problem is. I'm trying to move the compilation stage of each `cpp` file to a separate target. When it comes to the top-level file (`dotgazer.cpp`) it's not a problem and a general rule `%.o: %.cpp` works fine. But I can't get the second dependency to work. Here's how it looks now:

```
CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -I./include -pg -O2
VPATH=./src:./include

all: dotgazer.o dotgazer/Dot.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o dotgazer.out `pkg-config --libs opencv`

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

dotgazer/Dot.o: dotgazer/Dot.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

I've tried different variations of the `Dot.o` rule but none of them seems to work. The error I get with the one above is:

```
Fatal error: can't create dotgazer/Dot.o: No such file or directory
```

How should I do that? I'd most prefer to have the `.o` files in the same folders as their sources. Also, I'd be thankful for general rules (like `%.o: %.cpp`) as there are lots of source files and I don't want the Makefile to get too bloated. Thank you!

Comment: I might be being dumb, but aren't the `%.o: %.cpp` and `dotgazer/Dot.o: dotgazer/Dot.cpp` rules doubling up? Like, isn't the latter target already handled by the former?

Comment: @AdamGoodwin I thought that it will be working this way (only `%.o: %.cpp` rule needed). But it turns out - no. So I added the second rule especially for the second dependency and it still doesn't work. With just `%.o: %.cpp` rule the message is the same: `can't create dotgazer/Dot.o: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hmm, I just tried your makefile and it worked fine for me. It worked even with just the `%.o` target and without the `dotgazer/Dot.o` target. You haven't made a mistake with the filename or directory have you? Or are you doing something like running the makefile from somewhere other than its own directory?

Comment: I'm quite sure there were no misspellings or anything. I was running it from Netbeans, so I think it runs `make` in the folder of the Makefile. Anyway, the accepted answer solution works much better than I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `Makefile` is a bit to specific and thus error-prone. I suggest to look at my following example that is way more generic than yours.

My example takes advantage of `make`'s catalouge of implicit rules. For `cpp`-files exists a generic implicit rule already. So why should one not use it!?

The reference manual describes it as follows:

> **Compiling C++ programs**
>
> n.o is made automatically from n.cc, n.cpp, or n.C with a recipe of the form `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c`.

So if you have `%.o` files as prerequisites like in the rule `dotgazer.out: $(OBJS)` `make` applies above implicit rule to all those files automatically. Assumed you have set valid values for `CXX`, `CPPFLAGS` and/or `CXXFLAGS`.

Furthermore you usually don't need to add your sources by hand to a variable. Most of the time all the sources in your project's directory tree are needed to build the executable. If it's not the case you should consider to build a appropriate tree that reflects this.

Since `find` is responsible to assign the sources to `CPPFILES` we don't need to set `VPATH` either. Due to our usage of `find` and `patsubst` we have only one explicit file name in our `Makefile`. That make working on a real project with plenty of different sources much more smooth.

Of course you don't need the `all` and the `clean` rule. I just added these for convenience.

```
CXX=$(CROSS_COMPILE)g++
CPPFLAGS=-I./include
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -pg -O2
LDLIBS=`pkg-config --libs opencv`

CPPFILES=$(shell find . -name "*.cpp")
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(CPPFILES))

all: dotgazer.out
    @echo $(CPPFILES)
    @echo $(OBJS)

dotgazer.out: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

clean: 
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you! It has everything I needed, all files compiled separately, `.o` files in their respective folders. There's one issue though, the OpenCV functions are not recognized despite the `LDLIBS` settings. Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/zV9btgqN The `dotgazer.out` rule should look like this: `$(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)`. But still, this is a great answer!

Comment: You are right, i should change `$(CXX) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@` to `$(CXX) $(LDLIBS) -o $@ $^`. `g++ --help` sais that the input files should come after the options. Best regards

Comment: That's not the problem.  The `-o` can come at any time.  The problem is that the libraries _must_ come last (and the order in which libraries are listed can also be important).  Also `CPPFLAGS` are for C preprocessor flags (`-I` / `-D`); compiler flags like `-Wall -pg -O2` belong in `CXXFLAGS` (for C++).  To link, use something like `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)`

Comment: @MadScientist: Thanks for your comment. Especially that you point out the difference btw. `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` (i will edit my answer accordingly). I wasn't aware of that until now. Do you have any reference for your statement `...the libraries must come last`. Until today i never had any issues with my approach but thanks for saving me trouble in the future...